# How to merge github branch of text files into one text

Tags: git, github, github-actions

So keep hitting a problem, i've got a github cron that grabs txt files from all over the net, and then want to merge them into one file

Eg.
cron already grabs all the txt files and places into ./txt
then the merge would merge ./txt/*.txt to ./all.txt
so something like this

git merge-file ./all.txt ./all.txt ./txt/*.txt

but no matter what i do, it keeps overwriting all.txt with either the first or last txt file, and none of the others are merged..
Theres approx 40+ txt files at any time in this one folder and they are updated daily, so the cron gets those daily at 4am, all the gathering etc works fine, its the final merge i just cannot seem to get to work..

Any Ideas how to do this?

Comment: Assuming you just want the contents of all your text files into one file one after another, what about `cat.txt/*.txt > ./all.txt`?

Comment: now why dont they say that on github doc's? lol
Thanks @dan1st thats exactly what i needed.

Comment: Why would they? This is just appending and has nothing to do with git or GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

The UNIX-command `cat` allows you to read files and dump them to `stdout`.

You can read multiple files using `cat file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt` or use wildcards, e.g. `cat file*.txt`.

Another thing you can do is redirecting `stdout` to a file using `>`:

```
cat ./txt/*.txt > ./all.txt
```

This reads all `.txt` files in the directory `txt` and writes them to the file `all.txt`.